# Set a fixed length of part of a custom drawn shape in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, shapes, figma

I drew a bunch of shapes in Figma, copied them as svg code and converted them to a SwiftUI struct. The shape works great, but I am wondering when building shapes, whether it's in Figma or in SwiftUI if there's a way to make a part of the shape, or certain lines if you will, to be a specific length.

The shape I've build is basically a speechbubble. And the pointry part of the shape is what I want to be fixed. Because when setting a modifier of frame on the shape, it gets stretched or shrinks and looks weird.

```
struct SpeechBubblePointyTopCenter: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let width = rect.size.width
        let height = rect.size.height

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.9936*width, y: 0.21199*height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.9936*width, y: 0.96345*height))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.97228*width, y: 0.99269*height), control1: 
          CGPoint(x: 0.9936*width, y: 0.9796*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 
          0.98406*width, y: 0.99269*height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.02772*width, y: 0.99269*height))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0064*width, y: 0.96345*height), control1: 
          CGPoint(x: 0.01594*width, y: 0.99269*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 
          0.0064*width, y: 0.9796*height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0064*width, y: 0.21199*height))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.02772*width, y: 0.18275*height), control1: 
          CGPoint(x: 0.0064*width, y: 0.19584*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 
          0.01594*width, y: 0.18275*height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.38673*width, y: 0.18275*height))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.40404*width, y: 0.17059*height), control1: 
          CGPoint(x: 0.39359*width, y: 0.18275*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 
          0.40003*width, y: 0.17823*height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.48676*width, y: 0.01304*height))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.50055*width, y: 0.01294*height), control1: 
          CGPoint(x: 0.49014*width, y: 0.0066*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 
          0.49712*width, y: 0.00655*height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.58529*width, y: 0.17084*height))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.60247*width, y: 0.18275*height), control1: 
          CGPoint(x: 0.58931*width, y: 0.17833*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 
          0.59569*width, y: 0.18275*height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.97228*width, y: 0.18275*height))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.9936*width, y: 0.21199*height), control1: 
          CGPoint(x: 0.98406*width, y: 0.18275*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 
          0.9936*width, y: 0.19584*height))
        path.closeSubpath()

    return path

    }
}
```

This is the code of the shape, and hopefully will get some tips of how to fix it.
Also, if there is such a way. I would also like to apply it so that the lines are equal on each side of the pointy part of the speechbubble. Right now it's just in the center, by eye... Maybe there is a simpler way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the length of a line or curve in a custom `Shape` by simply modifying the x and y coordinates that the line/curve reaches to.

i.e. if your line is `path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.97228*width, y: 0.18275*height))`, you could make the line 10 px longer by simply adding/subtracting 10 to the y coordinate of the `CGPoint`, leaving you with something like `path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.97228*width, y: 0.18275*height - 10))`

Just remember to adjust all of your other lines accordingly, so that they all align and match up!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow completely. It's not that I want to make one line longer or shorter. What I would like is to have one line a fixed length, and/or fixed angle. So when the shape gets wider or shorter that specific part of the shape doesn't stretch but the whole shape gets larger.

Comment: I misunderstood, sorry about that! Right now, all of your points are being multiplied by the `height` and `width` of the `rect`. So, when you stretch the shape, you're stretching the `rect`, and thus changing the size of each line/curve. So, you need to use values for your x/y coordinates that aren't dependent on the `rect`. You could use UIScreen values, plan old x/y coordinates, and so on...